# Format number with convertNumber

Tags: java, numbers, format, oracle-adf

Format number with convertNumber in ADF.

```
 <af:inputText contentStyle="text-align:right">
          <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" pattern="#.###.###" type="number"/>
  </af:inputText>
```

If input value is `10000000` I want output of `10,000,000` but pattern not working.

Comment: I happen to be in the same spot. For some reason after entering the value in the input and then I refresh (F5) the page, the format is actually working. But can't make it work right after the control loses focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using the correct pattern but for wrong property.

Try this one..

```
<af:inputText contentStyle="text-align:right" id="it1" label="Test">
   <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" type="number" messageDetailConvertNumber="#,###,##"/>
</af:inputText>
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

In the .jspx file:

```
 <af:inputText 
        contentStyle="text-align:right"
        binding="#{myBean.myInput}"
        autoSubmit="true"
        valueChangeListener="#{myBean.ValueChangeListener}">

      <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" pattern="#.###.###" type="number"/>

  </af:inputText>
```

And now the bean:

```
public void ValueChangeListener(ValueChangeEvent valueChangeEvent) {
    try {
       AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addPartialTarget(this.myInput);            
   } catch (Exception e) {
        //Something went wrong
    }
}
```

**NOTES**

1. I'm on Oracle JDeveloper 12c